# Ignoring an object in struct is nil and not when it's an empty array

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

Is it possible to only use omitempty when an object is nil and not when it's an empty array?

I would like for the JSON marshaller to not display the value when an object is nil, but show `object: []` when the value is an empty list.

```json
objects: nil

{
  ...
}
```

```json
objects: make([]*Object, 0)

{
  ...
  "objects": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom json Marshal/Unmarshal functions for your struct. something like:

```golang
// Hello
type Hello struct {
    World []interface{} `json:"world,omitempty"`
}

// MarshalJSON()
func (h *Hello) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var hello = &struct {
        World []interface{} `json:"world"`
    }{
        World: h.World,
    }
    return json.Marshal(hello)
}

// UnmarshalJSON()
func (h *Hello) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var hello = &struct {
        World []interface{} `json:"world"`
    }{
        World: h.World,
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &hello)
}
```

Output:

```
{"world":[]}
```

Run above example: https://goplay.tools/snippet/J_iKIJ9ZMhT

Comment: Is there a better way to do something like this? I am currently using a large response that includes the status of the response as well as extra values for all of the possible responses, eg. projects, members, etc. Now, I'd want the JSON marshal to omit empty if the array is null or undefined in the request but show as [] when there is an empty list without redefining the struct for each one. Would the optimal solution be to just separate them into their own structs or?

Answer (score 0):

```
    t := []string{}
    json, _ := json.Marshal(struct {
        Data *[]string `json:"data,omitempty"`
    }{Data: &t})
    fmt.Println(string(json)) // Output: {"data":[]}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/ZPI39ioU-p5